# dwb_local_planner

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement the robot_navigation package into my robot. I clone the the entire robot_navigation folder into my catkin workspace and use catkin isolated make because when doing the regular catkin build it gives me a CMake Error "This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation....". The isolated build works, but when trying to run plan_node.launch in the dwb_local_planner/launch folder using roslaunch results in the error "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [dwb_local_planner/planner_node]: can't locate node [planner_node] in package [dwb_local_planner]. I have researched and everything I could find saying it wasn't sourced, but to my knowledge I did source it correctly. When running my other launch files in a separate folder it works correctly, but the terminal outputs the following:

```
[FATAL] [1517335343.278669007, 0.826000000]: Failed to create the dwb_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class dwb_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS with base class type nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS nav_core_adapter::LocalPlannerAdapter
[move_base-11] process has died [pid 28932, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=/robot_diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel __name:=move_base __log:=/home/USR/.ros/log/b1f50d24-05e7-11e8-a9e0-6c0b84aabb26/move_base-11.log].
log file: /home/USR/.ros/log/b1f50d24-05e7-11e8-a9e0-6c0b84aabb26/move_base-11*.log
```

My question is if anyone knows why it isn't launching correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281269/dwb_local_planner/) by [BellocRosenblat](https://answers.ros.org/users/33483/bellocrosenblat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-01-30**:
By robot_navigation, are you referring to the [navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) meta-package?
If so, why are you cloning the robot_navigation package directly into your workspace instead of installing it via `$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation`?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-01-30**:
There is no link, but I think the OP is referring to https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation (which contains a dwb_local_planner package)

**Comment by [BellocRosenblat](https://answers.ros.org/users/33483/bellocrosenblat/) on 2018-01-30**:
Yeah I was referring to https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation

**Comment by [rdelgadov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33433/rdelgadov/) on 2018-01-30**:
[this](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/issues/2) issue is similar, if you solve you can help or henoSH can help you.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-02-01**:
This issue is likely resolved for you via https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/pull/4 . Pull from github again and try compiling again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"This issue is likely resolved for you via https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation ..Pull from github again and try compiling again. **By. David Lu**" This was resolved in the pull. Thanks for the assistance.

---

Originally posted by [BellocRosenblat](https://answers.ros.org/users/33483/bellocrosenblat/) with karma: 26 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0